# R Plotly how to link text to bubbles in order to remove it when click on legend

Tags: r, plotly, bubble-chart

With plotly on R, I have a bubble scatter plot and I want to add black text on each bubble. I also have my bubbles colored following a column of my data frame (Type: Yes or No). On my legend, when I click on "Yes" it will remove the bubbles linked to "Yes" but the text is staying, even if I added a 'legendgroup=~Type' in both traces.

How can I remove the text linked to the bubble when the user click on the legend ?
It is possible but only if I set 'color = ~Type' in my text trace, but I want to keep the text in black.

Example :

```
df <- data.frame(Projet=c("A", "B", "C"), x=c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6), y=c(0.6, 0.5, 0.1), Size=c(2,5,8), Type=c("Yes", "Yes", "No"))

fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~ x, y = ~y) %>%
  add_trace(color = ~Type, size = ~Size,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', 
            sizes = c(20, 80),
            marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter',line = list(width = 2, color = 'gray60')),
            hovertext = ~paste('Projet:', Projet, '<br>Size (kE):', Size),
            hoverinfo="text", legendgroup=~Type) %>%
  add_trace(type="scatter", mode="text", text=~Projet, showlegend=F, legendgroup=~Type)



fig
```

Which gives :

[image]

And if I click on "Yes" in the legend :
[image]

=> I want to remove the "A" and "B" text in this case

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I looked at your Plotly object, you assigned three group names to the parameter `legendgroup`. The reason it worked in your initial call `add_trace` is that Plotly will split a trace by color. In your call for text, everything is the same color, so it didn't automatically split the trace.

In your call for the text, you need to add `split` to split the trace.

Check it out

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(Project = c("A", "B", "C"), x = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6),
                 y = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.1), Size = c(2,5,8), 
                 Type = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"))

fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~ x, y = ~y) %>%
  add_trace(color = ~Type, size = ~Size,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', 
            sizes = c(20, 80),
            marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter',
                          line = list(width = 2, color = 'gray60')),
            hovertext = ~paste('Project:', Project, '<br>Size (kE):', Size),
            hoverinfo = "text", legendgroup = ~Type) %>%
  add_trace(type = "scatter", mode = "text", text = ~Project, 
            showlegend = F, legendgroup = ~Type, split = ~Type) # <- I'm new!

fig
```

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Great answer Kat!

Comment: Can you please check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655646/r-display-popup-information-when-mouse-hovers-over-graph-visnetwork thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob - answered it... it's been a year and a half! I can't believe that it went unanswered. The visNetwork instructions are kind of a hot mess! Although there are an astronomical amount of things you can do with it, so I wouldn't want the job of trying to organize that! So... it's perfect, not a hot mess at all. (eek)